# Reactive Extension (Rx) GroupByUntil deadlock

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am trying to throttle CarUpdatedEventHandler coming from CarModel and sending them back to my MapListModel. I figured out some way to do it but unfortunately for unknown reason this causing me a deadlock.

The behavior of this code is right but causing the deadlock so my question is what else I can do?

```
var observable = Observable.FromEventPattern<CarUpdatedEventAgrs>(_carModel, "CarUpdatedEventHandler").GroupByUntil(
                key => key.EventArgs.Car, grp => grp.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(WATCHLIST_THROTTLE_DEPLAY_MS)));

observable.Subscribe(i =>
{
   CarUpdatedEventAgrs e = new CarUpdatedEventAgrs();
   e.Car = i.Key;
   this.RaiseEvent<CarUpdatedEventAgrs>(MapListUpdateEventHandler, e);
});
```

thanks for your time!

this code too causing deadlock:

```
var observable = Observable.FromEventPattern<CarUpdatedEventAgrs>(_carModel, "CarUpdatedEventHandler").GroupByUntil(
                    key => key.EventArgs.Car, grp => grp.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(WATCHLIST_THROTTLE_DEPLAY_MS)));

    observable.Subscribe(i =>
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Wait for deadlock");
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried to observe from the dispatcher?

Comment: @Brizio not at this time

Comment: Can you proide a snippet of what the MapListUpdate does? Maybe the problem relies there.

Comment: @Brizio check my post update, just by observing this cause the deadlock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally to be able to group and throttle, here's the way using Rx:

```
var throttledEvent = Observable.FromEventPattern<YourEventArgs>(ev => _yourObject.SubscribeEvent += ev, ev => _yourObject.SubscribeEvent -= ev).GroupBy(key => key.EventArgs.YourProperty).Select(o => o.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(YourThrottleTimeMs))).Merge();
```

That's fine this way!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is related to the fact that the Throttle operator acts on a different thread than the main one used by the dispatcher, therefore you might have some issues especially if you are trying to update in some way the UI. You should consider to use the ObserveOn operator before the subscription, and possibly observe on the main UI thread. Assuming that you are developing a WPF application this can be done like:

```
observable.ObserveOnDispatcher().Subscribe( // rest of the code
```

In order to do this you will need the Rx-WPF package. Obviously if you are uwing Windows Forms you will need the corresponding scheduler.

Comment: I tried to comment out the line: this.RaiseEvent<CarUpdatedEventAgrs>(MapListUpdateEventHandler, e); just in case that was the upper layer but still deadlock in Rx

Comment: I currently try your solution, I will tell you if the code still hangs. Thanks

Comment: I think that you might have misinterpreted `GroupByUntil`, as it is used to complete a sequence whenever the duration function you provide signals. In your case I think you are assuming that the `Throttle` operator is used as a selection function rather than a duration function. If this is the case you might want to use a combination of `GroupBy` and `SelectMany`. Something like `.GroupBy(key => key.EventArgs.Car).SelectMaby(grp => grp.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(WATCHLIST_THROTTLE_DEPLAY_MS))`